# Stuck on Bootstrap active class for my Nav Menu

Tags: bootstrap-4

Active Class to  Current page in Booststrap

I tried all kind of combinations, I succeeded in making menus active but I don't know how to disbale active on one menu while the other menu is active... they are all actice now !

**My Javascript:**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function ($) {
        let url = window.location.href;
        $('li a').each(function () {
            if (this.href === url) {
                $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Part of My HTML:**

```
<div class='container-fluid' style='margin-top:70px;'>
    <ul class='nav nav-pills'>
        <li>
            <a href='<?php $base_url ?>/admin/home.php'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-home'></span>  Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
           <a class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' href='<?php $base_url ?>/admin/home.php'>
                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-book'></span> LSNC Taskforce <span class='caret'></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <?php
                    $conn = new  mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'mcle') or die("Database  Connection Failed");

                    //Below We are  connectin gto Database and getting all events newer than a Year.
                    $sql = "SELECT  * FROM sessions where `date` > DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AND  event_type = 'taskforce'";
                    $res =  mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) 
                    {
                        echo "<li><a href='$base_url/admin/sessions.php?idx={$row['event_id']}'>  <span class=''>{$row['pro_title']}<span></a></li>";
                    }
                ?>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' href='<?php $base_url ?>/admin/home.php'>
                <span class='glyphicon  glyphicon-book'></span> LSNC All Staff <span class='caret'></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <?php
                    $sql = "SELECT  * FROM sessions where `date` > DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AND  event_type = 'allstaff'";
                    $res =   mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) 
                    {
                        echo "<li><a href='$base_url/admin/sessions.php?idx={$row['event_id']}'> <span class=''>{$row['pro_title']}<span></a></li>";
                    }
                ?>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

No Error mrssages it just wouldn't select active and current link, it is right now selecting home and the next 3  dropdown as Active...
Any Help is alwasy appreciated .
Many Thanks !
Ed-

Comment: why do you need to use javascript? You could just give the links address of the id of each section.

Comment: Thank you Sir, 
But what would I do with this dymanic URL ?
echo "<li><a href='$base_url/admin/sessions.php?idx={$row['event_id']}'> 
 <span class = ''>{$row['pro_title']}<span></a></li>";
Thank you .

Comment: Come on Help me guys ! i appreciate it .

Comment: @ Abdulaziz Yesuf
Any idea please ?

Comment: Anyone to help please ?

Comment: Hello @Nikolaus
Any idea you can help with here please ?

Comment: Hi @EdLachgar Can You Please Give Screenshot so we can understand better!

Comment: There you go.. I uploaded some pics, 
Now this is what I am using as JS:
    
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("ul.nav li").click(function() {
        $("ul.nav li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
         });
         });
       </script>

Comment: My issue is that the Actice class works but doesn't stay active, the moment I click, the link becomes Blue as it should , but only for a couple of seconds before it disappears and the link is no longer active.
The dropdown is going to be a problem I think... because it is dynamic .
Any idea and help will be mightly appreciated .
Ed-

Comment: Any chance Anyone before I close this Post at all ?
Much appreciated in advance !

Comment: @HamzaLachi 
Any chance ? this must not be this hard :-) I know I am missing in a little detail here ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Guys, Thank you All especially @Khalid Khan who took time to answer my question.. I finally found the answer:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
var url = window.location;
// Will only work if string in href matches with location
$('ul.nav a[href="' + url + '"]').parent().addClass('active');

// Will also work for relative and absolute hrefs
$('ul.nav a').filter(function () {
    return this.href == url;
}).parent().addClass('active').parent().parent().addClass('active');
});
</script>
Now my dropdown is working[enter image description here][1] as expected. Thank you again, All.
Ed-
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your Javascript code to this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function ($) {
        let url = window.location.href;
        $('li a').each(function () {
            if($(this).hasClass('active')){
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            }
            if (this.href === url) {
                $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you @Khalid Khan...
I tried your code, a bit better but my dropdown still doesn't get actice class when i click on it.
Anything else that is not Dropdown is working fine ..

Comment: <ul class = 'nav nav-pills'>
 <li><a href = '<?php $base_url ?>.....><span class = 
       'glyphicon glyphicon-home'></span> Home</a></li>

 <li><a class = 'dropdown-toggle ' data-toggle = 'dropdown'  href = '#' >
  <span class = 'glyphicon glyphicon-book'></span> 
       <span class = 'caret'></span></a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    .....
    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) 
     {
     echo "<li><a href='$base_url/......php? 
       dx={$row['event_id']}'><span >{$row['pro_title']}<span></a></li>";